# Is it possible to add video files as a texture face in a cubemap?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, oculus

I'm using unity in combination with the Oculus. I'm using a cubemap to add 360 photo environment to my scene. So the next step is to make a 360 video environment and I'm wondering if it is possible to add 6 video files to a cubemap? If so, what extra steps do I needs to make. And if not, how can I create a similar effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want an equirectangular movie and put in on a sphere with [reversed normals](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/ReverseNormals). Much less problems this way.

Make the sphere large (like 1000 units, but look out for the camera far rendering distance). If the camera moves around a lot, attach it to the camera (so it will be in the center).

Depending on your needs, you will might have a problem with movie resolution, there are fixes on the asset store.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will give it a go! I figured it wasn't possible/practical to use cubemaps. I'm swamped with work right now, but I will keep you all posted! Also if people have other ideas I'm all ears!